# visualizing 3d data volume in matlab

Tags: matlab, data-visualization, matlab-figure

I have many points in 3d (x,y,z), and for each point I have it's disparity (0-10 value), different points can have the same disparity.

I want to plot this data that each point will have a color according to it's disparity.

I want it to be something like this picture: (small disparity will have one color, and as it's gets bigger the color changes)

[image]

how can I do it?

Comment: Even though the above plot is not your intended one, I still think it's really cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`scatter3`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html):

```
x = rand(1,1000);
y = rand(1,1000);
z = rand(1,1000); %// example x, y, z
d = x.^2+y.^2+z.^2; %// example disparity
scatter3(x,y,z,8,d,'fill');
colorbar
```

The fourth input argument to `scatter3` is marker size. The fifth determines color. `'fill'` uses filled markers.

[image]